# How to set RabbitMQ logging format to single line?

Tags: rabbitmq

I want to have RabbitMQ log entry to single line instead of multiline. How could I do that?

I have set `log.file.formatter.single_line = true` in rabbitmq.conf, but then RabbitMQ fails to start. In addition - if it would be possible to set in the runtime, without restarting the server - that woud be great.

Using 3.10.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but then RabbitMQ fails to start

Have you checked the log files for the error?

https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/search?q=single_line

The correct setting is `on`, not `true` ([source code](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/blob/adb6e0468df0234bc920ca0a2b4c20227edfa2bd/deps/rabbit/priv/schema/rabbit.schema#L1423-L1426))

> if it would be possible to set in the runtime, without restarting the server

There's probably a very convoluted way to do that but really it's just easier to change the setting and restart RabbitMQ.

---

<sub>**NOTE:** the RabbitMQ team monitors the `rabbitmq-users` [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rabbitmq-users) and only sometimes answers questions on StackOverflow.</sub>